# Create a matrix with initiated data in python then modify a cell

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create a 3x3 matrix with lists in python with initial value 0 then modify a cell in it like the following:

`matrix = [[0]*3]*3`

When I assign the cell x=1 y=1 the value 1 as the following:

`matrix[1][1] = 1`

The result is :

`[[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,1,0]]`

but if I initiate the matrix as the following :

`matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`

the output is correct as the following :

`[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]`

Can someone explain me why the output in the first example is incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `*` operator doesn't create new arrays in multi-dimensional lists it simply copies them.

You create the first list with `[0]*3` and the other lists are simply copies of that same list.  And since lists are mutable, editing one of them edit's all of them.

In your second example all three of the sub-lists are hardcoded and unique, so editing one of them only edits that one.

If you used list-comprehension to create the matrix it would also create unique sub-lists.

Like this:

```
matrix = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

Comment: Thank you now I have understood the utility of the * operator while creating lists :D

Answer (score 0):

When you use * it copy and refers to same reference address

```
matrix = [[0] * 3]*3
print(matrix)
for i in matrix:
    print(id(i))
```

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
2799443720
2799443720
2799443720

[Program finished]
```

The id is same so the change will be occured for all
You can alternatively use for loop to avoid this.
Hope it helps... :)

Comment: Thank you man, clear and great explanation :D